# Weird ValueError when concatenating multiple csv files using a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation, list-comprehension, valueerror

I am trying to construct a single pandas DataFrame that includes the contents of multiple csv_files.

Here are the two methods I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Method 1
for f in csv_files:
    r = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(f))
    df = pd.concat([df, r], axis=1)

# Method 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_files), axis=1))
```

**Problem:**
I can produce the desired outcome, but I would like to learn about a weird problem I have with the code.

*Method 1* works when ran in a terminal, as well when ran in an interactive window (jupyter).
However, *method 2* produces a value error when ran in a terminal, and works normally when ran in an interactive window (using a jupyter cell).

The value error is: "ValueError: No objects to concatenate"

I would like to learn what causes the problem with *pd.concat* when executing the script in terminal (and why it works in jupyter cell). I am using VS code, if anyone is wondering.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here is the full error message produced by method 2. It seems that the list comprehension doesn't work as it should:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path_name", line 15, in 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_files), axis=1))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 294, in concat
op = _Concatenator(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 351, in **init**
raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: Both work fine in my terminal. Have you checked both are running the same python version?

Comment: both work fine for me, too. trying to remove the obvious: are you sure the terminal one is running in the same directory? what OS is it? and if Windows, are you using WSL by chance?

Comment: I am running the latest version of VS code on my Mac. Also, both interpreters are running python 3.9.0 from the same directory.